# Extract specific required data from netCDF using python

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, netcdf, netcdf4

I am learning python and I am working with some netCDF files. Suppose I have temperature data from 1950-2020 and I want data for only 1960-2015. How should I extract it.

Answer (score 0):

You should give more info about the data. What kind of output do you want like export as nc file or dataframe or what ?

Answer (score 0):

On linux and macOS, you can do this easily with [nctoolkit](https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html). Example:

```
import nctoolkit as nc
ds = nc.open_data("infile.nc")
ds.subset(years = range(1960, 2016))
```